# assembler удаление символа по нажатию клавиши

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, dos

Я написал программу на  asm,  которая демонстрирует работу буфера клавиатуры.
Не знаю как сделать удаление символа с консоли по нажатию определённой клавиши.

Код программы.

```
use16
org 100h
mov ax,0040h
mov es,ax
mov si,0080h
mov ax,[es:si]
mov si,ax
mov bx,0
mov dx,32
l2:
 cmp bx,dx
 ja l3
 mov cx,16
 mov ah,00h
 int 16h

l1:
 mov ax,[es:si]
 call print_word
 call endl
 add si,2

 loop l1
 sub  si,32
 call endl
 jmp l2


 l3:
 mov ah,8
 int 21h

print_word:

print_str:
endl:
 push di
 mov di,endline
 call print_str
 pop di
 ret
delite:       ;Если вызвать эту процедуру по то значения просто будут заполняться 
 push ax      ;нулями. 
 mov ax,0040h ;другого не придумал(
 mov es,ax
 mov si,0080h
 mov ax,[es:si]
 mov si,ax
 mov ax,si
 mov ax,0x00
 call print_word
 call endl
 pop ax
 ret

endline db 13,10,'$'
buffer rb 5
```

Comment: Не понято что такое "на консоли". Если бы надо было удалить на кране, да, я бы сказал, что надо затереть пробелом или нулем. А когда это происходит в буфере, то обычно достаточно просто передвинуть указатель хвоста ближе к началу